# Intersection Volume

Tags: plotting, graphics, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

In a cube of side "a", a sphere with center in one of the vertices intersects another sphere located in the vertex opposite to the previous one. What is the volume of the intersection?

First I tried to draw the situation
The equation of one of the spheres centered at the origin is

**$$x^2+y^2+z^2 =a^2$$** 
And the one located on the opposite vertex will be

**$$(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2+(z-a)^2 =a^2$$**

2 questions
How to plot the situation?
How to calculate the common volume?

I used several commands but I did not get the cube and the 2 spheres at the same time in a drawing

Thanks in advance

**Edited: There was an error in the radios of the spheres, they have radius "a", similar to the edges of the cube**

Comment: Try this: `RegionIntersection[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 3], Ball[{1, 1, 1}, 3]] // Volume`

Comment: "Unable to compute the volume of region \
RegionIntersection[Ball[{0,0,0},3],Ball[{1,1,1},3]]"  :(

Comment: Note that your problem statement mentions nothing about the radius. Are you sure that's all you've been given?

Comment: Edited: There was an error in the radios of the spheres, they have radius "a", similar to the edges of the cube

Comment: c = {1, 1, 1};
Show[ContourPlot3D[{(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 + (z - 1)^2 == 1, 
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> None], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[{{0, 0, 0}, c}], 
   Line[{{0, 0, 0}, c}]}]]   --> This is the idea
Similar code in forum
As I get the whole spheres, and the volume

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the plotting - with `a` equal to 1:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], Green, Ball[], Red, Ball[{1, 1, 1}], 
  Opacity[0.6], Blue, Cuboid[]}]
```

[image]

As suggested by J.M., it is possible to derive a symbolic expression for the region using

```
region = Simplify[RegionMember[RegionIntersection[
    Ball[], Ball[{1, 1, 1}]], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z} ∈ Reals]

x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && (-1 + x)^2 + (-1 + y)^2 + (-1 + z)^2 <= 1
```

which is the same as the OPs expression with a=1.

To plot just the intersection:

```
RegionPlot3D[region, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

To find the volume, integrate over the region of intersection:

```
NIntegrate[Boole[region], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]

0.107742
```

Comment: ok , What instruction do I now take to calculate the common volume of the two spheres

Comment: Here's the symbolic way to get the integration region: `Simplify[RegionMember[RegionIntersection[Ball[], Ball[{1, 1, 1}]], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z} ∈ Reals]`

Comment: Hey what if I want to find intersection region of two ellipsoid instead?

Comment: @Rajat Zope -- Define the region and then integrate over Boole[region].