# Volume of solids of revolution through two equations

Tags: geometry

I would like to get the area formed by two equations and the volume of the solid formed by this area around the Y axis.

```
Solve[x^2==6x-2x^2,x]
```

> {{x->0},{x->2}}

```
Plot[{x^2,6x-2x^2},{x,0,2}]
```

[image]

I tried to use this idea but did not succeed;

[Intersection Volume](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144197/intersection-volume)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose another way. You can use `DiscretizeRegion` to create a region from the `ParametricRegion`. Then, calculate the volume:

```
\[ScriptCapitalR]1 = 
 DiscretizeRegion[
 ParametricRegion[{{x, y, z},6 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 2 (x^2 + y^2) > z && x^2 + y^2 <= 4 &&x^2 + y^2 <= z && z >= 0}, {{x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, 0, 5}}],
 MaxCellMeasure -> #, ImageSize -> Small] & /@ {Automatic,0.1, 0.01,0.0005};
 vols1 = Volume[\[ScriptCapitalR]1[[#]]] & /@ Range[4];
 Row@(Labeled[\[ScriptCapitalR]1[[#]],Style["Volume = " <> ToString[vols1[[#]]], 12, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], Top]&/@ Range[4])
```

[image]

or use `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`:

```
\[ScriptCapitalR]2 = 
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
 ParametricRegion[{{x, y, z},6 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 2 (x^2 + y^2) > z && x^2 + y^2 <= 4 &&x^2 + y^2 <= z && z >= 0}, {{x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, 0, 5}}],
 MaxCellMeasure -> #, ImageSize -> Small] & /@ {Automatic,0.1, 0.01,0.0005};
 vols2 = Volume[\[ScriptCapitalR]2[[#]]] & /@ Range[4];
 Row@(Labeled[\[ScriptCapitalR]2[[#]],Style["Volume = " <> ToString[vols2[[#]]], 12, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], Top]&/@ Range[4])
```

[image]

In both cases, the value of the calculated volume, and obviously the appearance, depends on the value of the option `MaxCellMeasure`, as can be deduced from the plots.

It seems that `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` has a greater accuracy.

The volume can be calculated directly from `ParametricRegion`, which is more exact, and compared to previous values:

```
NestList[N,Volume[ParametricRegion[{{x, y, z}, 
6 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 2 (x^2 + y^2) > z && x^2 + y^2 <= 4 && x^2 + y^2 <= z && z >= 0},
{{x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, 0, 5}}]],1]

(*{8 \[Pi], 25.1327}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

The area is simply given by

```
Integrate[ 6x - 2x^2 - x^2, {x, 0, 2}]
(* 4 *)
```

Using the [cylinder method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration), the volume is given by

```
2 Pi*Integrate[x*Abs[6 x - 2 x^2 - x^2], {x, 0, 2}]
(* 8 Pi *)
```

You can also get the area with `Area[ImplicitRegion[x^2 <= y <= (6 x - 2 x^2), {x, y}]]`. For the volume, I would start by plotting the region with `RevolutionPlot3D[6 x - 2 x^2 - x^2, {x, 0, 2}]`. There a many posts about this on the website.