# The volume of the region enclosed by $x=y^3$, $x=0$, $y=2$

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, visualization, image3d

The volume of the region enclosed by $x=y^{3}$, $x=0$, $y=2$, revolved around the X-axis is?

My question is, how would that solid be represented?

Comment: Do you want to represent it graphically (like with [`ContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html)), or do you want a region ([`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) or [`ParametricRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html)), or do you just want to calculate the volume ([`RegionMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html) or good ol' fashioned integration)?

Comment: @aardvark2012 i try to calculate the volume

Comment: For the visualization `ContourPlot3D` might be another way to go: `ContourPlot3D[{x == (Sqrt[y^2 + z^2])^3, Sqrt[y^2 + z^2] == 2}, {x, 0, 8}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]`.

Comment: [posibly related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158971/volume-of-solids-of-revolution-through-two-equations/158988#158988)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

*Thanks to @ubpdqn for pointing out that it should be `{x, 0, 8}`, not `{x, 0, 2^(1/3)}`.*

I think this is what you want:

```
region = ImplicitRegion[
    y^2 + z^2 < x^(2/3),
    {{x, 0, 8}, {y, -2, 2},{z, -2, 2}}
];

Volume @ DiscretizeRegion @ region
```

> 60.1229

The discretization isn't very accurate, so alternatives to produce a more accurate answer are:

```
Integrate[π x^(2/3), {x, 0, 8}]
%//N

NIntegrate[1, {x,y,z} ∈ region]
```

> 96 π/5
>
> 60.3186
>
> 60.3186

Visualization:

```
Region[region, Axes->True, AxesLabel->{"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Comment: but I want to see the figure in three dimensions

Comment: @Python241820 Visualization added.

Comment: @CarlWoll with sincere respect I think the region "enclosed by" $x=y^{1/3}, x=0,y=2$ is not the region you define. I am very happy to be corrected. I apologize for any misconception.

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks, I think I fixed it, although it still disagrees with your interpretation.

Comment: @CarlWoll Carl is Integrate[\[Pi]*(4 - x^(2/3)), {x, 0, 8}]. = 64pi/5

Comment: @CarlWoll I accept I may have misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1):

I have interpreted the region as shown in the filled region of the plot below (the area enclosed by $x=y1/3,x=0,y=2$ rotated around the x-axis. I am happy to delete if I have misunderstood. So,

```
Plot[{x^(1/3), 2}, {x, 0, 8}, Epilog -> {Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 2}}]},
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
reg = ImplicitRegion[
  x^(2/3) < y^2 + z^2 < 4, {{x, 0, 8}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}}]
s[u_, v_] := {u ^3, u Cos[v], u Sin[v]}
pp = ParametricPlot3D[s[u, v], {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Red];
rp = RegionPlot3D[reg, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3]];
Show[rp, pp]
```

The volume can be determined by using cylindrical coordinates and subtracting from bounding cylinder...

```
  vol = Pi 2^2 8 - 
  Integrate[ r , {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 0, 8}, {r, 0, z^(1/3)}]
```

[image]