# Volume of a 3D implicit region

Tags: numerical-integration, regions, computational-geometry, inequalities

To find the volume of the following region:

```
fn[x_, y_, z_]:= Abs[0.7*x*Exp[I*y] + 0.3*Sqrt[x^2 + 8*10^-5] 
 + Sqrt[x^2 + 3*10^-3]*0.02*Exp[I*z]]

R = ImplicitRegion[fn[x, y, z]<=3*10^-3, {{x, 0, 0.015}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}, {z, 0, 2*Pi}}]

RegionPlot3D[
 fn[x, y, z] <= 3*10^-3, {x, 0, 0.015}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}, {z, 0, 2*Pi}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]], Mesh -> None]
```

[image: Plot of region of interest]

Using `Volume`:

```
Volume[R]
```

> Volume::nmet: Unable to compute the volume of region

Using `NIntegrate`:

```
NIntegrate[
  Boole[fn[x, y, z] <= 3*10^-3], {x, 0, 0.015}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}, {z, 0, 
   2*Pi}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 50000}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 3] // Timing
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: 
>       Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
>
> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 50000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations... NIntegrate obtained 0.12219642052793653 and 0.007515502934285486 for the integral and error estimates.
>
> {19.25, 0.122196}

The result does not converge.

Using `MonteCarlo`:

```
NIntegrate[
  Boole[fn[x, y, z] <= 3*10^-3], {x, 0, 0.015}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}, {z, 0, 
   2*Pi}, Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^12, 
    "RandomSeed" -> 9}, PrecisionGoal -> 3] // Timing
```

> {8.39063, 0.121479}

This is slow, and if `PrecisionGoal -> 5` is set,

```
NIntegrate[
 Boole[fn[x, y, z] <= 3*10^-3], {x, 0, 0.015}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}, {z, 0, 
  2*Pi}, Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^12, 
   "RandomSeed" -> 9}, PrecisionGoal -> 5]
```

It does not give a result even after running for more than 2 minutes.

**I hope to find a better way to calculate the volume of this region with:**

1. High accuracy: at least `PrecisionGoal -> 5`
2. Good error estimate
3. Fast

Comment: Usually, I would try `Volume[DiscretizeRegion[R,MaxCellMeasure->0.01]]` with different values for `MaxCellMeasure`. However, it fails in this case for some reason...

Comment: Try to `Rationalize` the expression you use in `fn` and use symbolic bounds over numerical constants whenever possible (e.g. 15/1000 instead of 0.015). This often helps, because it enables arbitrary precision results without loss of precision/accuracy, which can cause problems (slow convergence warnings) in numerical methods like `NIntegrate`. It also helps avoid ugly results when a symbolic integration is possible.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher.  Yeah, I also found that `DiscretizeRegion[R]` failed in this case.

Comment: @Thies Heidecke  Thanks for your advice. I rationalized the expression and found the result is same as the above.

Answer (score 7):

I think the main issue is the axes bounds are quite disproportionate and that's effecting the sampling.

Here's your region scaled to the unit cube:

```
R2 = ImplicitRegion[fn[3 x/200, 2π y, 2π z] <= 3*10^-3, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}];

reg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[R2, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, MaxCellMeasure -> .0001]
```

[image]

```
0.015 * (2π)^2 * Volume[reg]
```

> ```
> 0.121605
> ```

If we clean up `fn` a bit, we get a noticeable speedup in `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`:

```
f2[x_, y_, z_] = ComplexExpand[Rationalize[fn[x, y, z]]]^2;

R3 = ImplicitRegion[f2[3 x/200, 2π y, 2π z] <= (3*10^-3)^2, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}];
```

Compare:

```
timeDisc[r_] := First[AbsoluteTiming[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[r, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, MaxCellMeasure -> .0001]]];

{timeDisc[R2], timeDisc[R3]}
```

> ```
> {1.92265, 1.18681}
> ```

Note that this approach works on the original unscaled region, but there are strange fringes and it's very slow:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[R, {{0, 0.015}, {0, 2π}, {0, 2π}}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, MaxCellMeasure -> .0001]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is what I got without rescaling. I am wondering why those defects disappear doing that... +1

Comment: My guess is since the y and z bounds are so much larger, they were sample more. The fact that the fringes are parallel to the x axis seem (to me) to support this.

Comment: @ José Antonio Díaz Navas @ Chip Hurst       Thanks for your suggestions. It is true that If we set the `MaxCellMeasure` smaller, we can get a result of greater accuracy. Can I know the total error estimate of the volume when using the method of `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` and `Volume`?

Comment: @Chip Hurst  I tried the `timeDisc` some times with MMA 10.3 and found the result varied from about 10s to 50s even though I used `ClearSystemCache` before `timeDisc`, so I failed to compare `timeDisc[R2]` and `timeDisc[R3]`. Does it happen in your computer?

Comment: I am curious about what kind of algorithm is used by the `Volume` when the input of `Volume` is the output of `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` as in the above case.

Comment: @K.D, the documentation says that `Volume` uses `Integrate` or `NIntegrate` to do the calculations.

Comment: @ José Antonio Díaz Navas Thank you. Can you tell me which documentation? I find `Volume[reg]` is much faster than `Integrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] reg]`, and the results of them are not identical.

Comment: @K.D I was in 11.1, so there must have been an improvement in discretization sometime in between. I just reran things in 10.3 and 11.1 and got timings `{19.5529, 8.05711}` and `{1.94618, 1.08445}`, respectively.

Comment: As for finding the error in `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`, I'm not sure how to go about that. And for how to find the volume of a mesh, one way is to use the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) to relate surface area and volume. (Not sure if that's what `Volume` uses or not). Here's a proof of concept: `In[18]:= Volume[reg] - Total[#1.Cross[#2, #3] & @@@ MeshPrimitives[reg, 2][[All, 1]]]/6
Out[18]= -1.30757*10^-13`.

Comment: @Chip Hurst Thanks a lot. It's a good idea to use the divergence theorem to calculate the volume of a mesh. I got the timing of `Volume[reg]` and `Total[#1.Cross[#2, #3] & @@@ MeshPrimitives[reg, 2][[All, 1]]]/6` to be about 0.008s and 11s. The `Volume[reg]` is much faster, so there should be something more in the `Volume`. This method of using `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` and `Volume` speeds up the calculation a lot, and will be more practical if there is an error estimate, which is important to me.

Comment: @K.D yes my implementation is quite slow and inefficient. Volume is using a much more efficient lower level implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this with MMA 11.2 (macOs 10.13.3) in my old Intel I3. First, I have simplified a bit your `fn` as it involves `Abs`, and by setting the definition of `ImplicitFucntion` in a standard form:

```
fn[x_, y_, z_] := 8.4*10^-6 + 0.5804 x^2 + 0.00375659 x Sqrt[1 + 12500 x^2] Cos[y] + 
0.000885438 Sqrt[3 + 1000 x^2] (1. x Cos[y - z] + 0.00383326 Sqrt[1 + 12500 x^2] Cos[z])

R = ImplicitRegion[fn[x, y, z] <= 9/1000000 && 
                   0 <= x <= 0.015 && 0 <= y <= 2 Pi && 0 <= z <= 2 Pi, {x, y, z}];

NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] R,Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^6}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 5]
```

The high number of points used is to provide the required `PrecisionGoal`, and after 11.5 sec:

```
NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 1000100 integrand evaluations. 
NIntegrate obtained 0.12154680553578552` and 0.00023916058934647544` for the integral 
and error estimates.

(* 0.121547 *)
```

which is slow, and not enough.

However, by using `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`, we can use `Volume`. This is quite slow, as we need to represent the region with enough accuracy (see also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158971/volume-of-solids-of-revolution-through-two-equations/158988#158988)), but provides a reference value for the volume calculated by using `NIntegrate`:

```
R2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[R, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.000075];
Volume[R2]

(* 0.121502 *)
```

[image]

For `MaxCellMeasure->0.00006` the volume is 0.121509.

By means of:

```
NIntegrate[Boole[fn[x, y, z] <= 9/1000000], {x, 0, 0.005, 0.01, 0.015}, 
{y, 0, 2/3 Pi, 4/3 Pi, 2*Pi}, {z, 0, 2/3 Pi, 4/3 Pi, 2*Pi}, 
Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^7, "RandomSeed" -> 9}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 5] // AbsoluteTiming
```

I get (again, very slow):

```
NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 10000100 integrand evaluations. 
NIntegrate obtained 0.12149430710916392` and 0.000041400109821011765` for the integral 
and error estimates.

(* {20.1802, 0.121494} *)
```

Well, It seems that your problem is not so easy to make it more efficient. I always used in this case the `MonteCarlo` method as the faster one with `NIntegrate`. However, an expert on numerical integration can explore the multiple options to obtain a proper combination of them to speed up the calculation.

The use of `Volume` seems to be the faster as long as the process in obtaining the `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` will be also fast. It was so to achieve the required `PrecisionGoal` in my computer, compared to `NIntegrate` .

Hope this helps.