# Why is this RevolutionPlot3D empty in the middle around x = 0.5?

Tags: plotting, functions

Why is this RevolutionPlot3D empty in the middle around x = 0.5 like this?

```
RevolutionPlot3D[Min[x^2, x^2 - 2 x + 1], {x, 0, 1}, 
 RevolutionAxis -> "X", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please write an *INFORMATIVE* title... one that deals with the content of your question more specifically.  After all, what do YOU think the average reader understands from your title alone?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork sorry for that. I didn't notice much as it was the only thing in my mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Original answer**

```
RevolutionPlot3D[Min[x^2, x^2 - 2 x + 1], {x, 0, 1}, 
 RevolutionAxis -> "X", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Exclusions -> None]
```

> [image: revplot]

**Edit: many thanks to @Bob Hanlon for suggesting the use of [`MaxRecursion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html)**

```
RevolutionPlot3D[Min[x^2, x^2 - 2 x + 1], {x, 0, 1}, 
 RevolutionAxis -> "X", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Exclusions -> None, 
 MaxRecursion -> 6]
```

> [image: rev2]

Comment: +1 `MaxRecursion -> 6` is useful

Comment: Thanks, probably a bit off topic but how would you represent this volume by ImplicitRegion? I want to know this so I can calculate volume to confirm with my other method using integral.

Comment: @BobHanlon indeed. A very nice alternative. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @hana I guess you mean something like the answer provided [`here`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165560/volume-of-a-3d-implicit-region) right?

Comment: `rgn = ImplicitRegion[(y^2 + z^2 <= x^4 && 0 <= x <= 1/2) || (y^2 + z^2 <= (x^2 - 2 x + 1)^2 && 1/2 < x <= 1), {x, y, z}];` Then `Volume[rgn]` evaluates to `Pi/80`

Comment: I found an old thread and this works too.
`ImplicitRegion[
 z^2 + y^2 <= Min[x^2, x^2 - 2 x + 1]^2 && 0 <= x <= 1, {x, y, z}]`

Comment: @hana I think that the main idea -which was initially demonstrated by Bob here- is to use $x,y,z$ as variables such that `Volume` is well-defined. Great suggestions by both!!!

Comment: Thanks for the update and the MaxRecursion -> 6 looks much nicer!